# What does setDefaultButton do?

Tags: jdialog

```
sendButton = new JButton("Send");
sendButton.addActionListener(this);
sendButton.setActionCommand("SEND");
getRootPane().setDefaultButton(sendButton);
```

What does `setDefaultButton` do? I'm trying to add `sendButton` as my default button.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29):

> The default button is the button which will be activated when a UI-defined activation event (typically the Enter key) occurs in the root pane regardless of whether or not the button has keyboard focus (unless there is another component within the root pane which consumes the activation event, such as a JTextPane).

In other words, it's the button which will be activated by default, e.g. in a dialog "Do you want to delete this file? [Yes]/[No]", it would be wise to set [No] as the default button, to avoid catastrophic errors.

Note that setting it as default does not mean **adding** it to the panel. It should already have been added, otherwise it's meaningless to set it as default:

> For default activation to work, the button must be an **enabled descendent of the root pane** when activation occurs.

That is, if you didn't add it to the panel already, it won't even show up, so setting it as default should only happen after that.

You should have a JPanel or something similar (not necessarily the rootPane), say `panel`, where the button should be added to via `panel.add(sendButton)`, before calling `getRootPane().setDefaultButton(sendButton)`. Which is, by the way, strictly optional.